# Highcharts/Highstocks jQuery - Scroll, Zoom and Margin issue

Tags: php, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm working on displaying my stock data live in charts. I am using Highcharts for it. But I'm not getting proper output of it. See the image

[image]

Problems:

1. **Margin**:
   As you can see the margin on the y axis is very high, because of which my ohlc data is showing very thin.
2. **Some points are not getting highlighted on hovering over them**:
   When I try to hover on some points it does not show me that point's data. It sticks on the previous point's data.
3. **Blue Area shade at the bottom**:
   As you can see the blue area at the bottom is not changing according to data in particular region.
4. **Scroll issue**:
   When I try to move the scroll bar or try to increase its size, it gets stuck at the extreme right side. (So not able to move scroll since it gets stuck on the right side when I try to move it.)
5. **Zoom Issue**:
   When I try to zoom in with zoom options I'm not able to zoom ro my data. For all zooms it remains same as "All" option

I have made some changes in [this script](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume): (Two panes, candlestick and volume) to receive my data.

I am retrieving all live data from PHP file using $.getJSON and doing all thing.
I can't create a fiddle of it because it's my live stock market data.

Here is the code :

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('get_data.php?type=ohlc', function(data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length;

            alert(data);

        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i]['SQLDT'], // the date
                parseFloat(data[i]['OPN']), // open
                parseFloat(data[i]['HGH']), // high
                parseFloat(data[i]['LWE']), // low
                parseFloat(data[i]['CLS']) // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i]['SQLDT'], // the date
                parseFloat(data[i]['VOL']) // the volume
            ])
        }



        // set the allowed units for data grouping
        var groupingUnits = [[
            'week',                         // unit name
            [1]                             // allowed multiples
        ], [
            'month',
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]];

        // create the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                alignTicks: false
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Historical'
            },

             xAxis:[ {
        min: 10
    },{
         min: 10
    }],

            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: 200,
                lineWidth: 2,

            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: 300,
                height: 100,
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],
              scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: may i please know the reasons for downvotes?

Comment: i m facing these problems same time and they might no be occurring bcz of the many reasons. I guess der could be only one bug in coding like margin or somethig bcoz of which chart is very much distorted

Answer (score 1):

> **Margin:**
>       As you can see the margin on y axis is very high !! because of which my ohlc data is showing very thin.

Try [adjusting the max](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.max) to better utilize real estate

> **Some points not getting highlighted on hovering over them:**
>       when i tried to hover on some points it does not show me that point's data. it sticks on the previous point's data.

Try disabling [Stick Tracking](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.stickyTracking)

> **Blue Area shade at the bottom:**
>       As you can see the blue area at the bottom is not changing according to data in particular region.

Make sure the navigator is pointing to the correct [base series](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.baseSeries)

> **Scroll issue:**
>       When i try to move scroll bar or try to increase it's size, it gets stuck at extreme right side. (So not able to move scroll since it gets stick in right side when i try to move it.)
>
> **Zoom Issue:**
>       When i try to zoom in with zoom options m not able to zoom ro my data. for all zooms it remains same as "All" option

These issues can come if something else is broken in your javascript. Check console for errors.

I can understand that you can't share your real code, but a jsFiddle reproduction of the issue may help. Use dummy values, or share the resultant json of the $.getJSON call